# Mac OS - `brew list` so that casks are exlcuded

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I can list casks using `brew list --cask`, but I'm not sure how to output a list of installed packages which are not casks.

Eg, if i have done:

```
brew install pyenv
brew install --cask iterm2
```

I would like to have some `brew list --not-cask` such that `pyenv` was output

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to list formula only:

```shell
$ brew list --formula
```

See more options with this command:

```shell
$ brew list --help
```